# Parse Unpin Does Not Remove Object From Local Datastore

Tags: ios, parse-platform

This should work.

Here is one of many attempts to get this figured out

```
            myTrainingSessions[indexPath.row].unpinInBackgroundWithBlock{ (succ, e) -> Void in
            if succ == true {

                // just remove from table view etc
                self.myTrainingSessions[indexPath.row].deleteEventually()
                self.myTrainingSessions.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

                // Shows that my object is still in datastore!
                // object should be UNPINNED - but appers in this result....
                var query = PFQuery(className:TrainingSession.parseClassName())
                query.whereKey(self.userType(), equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
                query.fromLocalDatastore().ignoreACLs()
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil { return }
                    if let result = objects as? [TrainingSession] {
                        println("local results")
                        println(result)
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

I do a query after unpinning and the object is still there.

Comment: I did get this to work in the end, only via brute force trial and error.

Comment: I have same problem. When I unpin an object previously pinned it is still present in the local storage.

Comment: @Dragouf did you sort it out ?

Comment: No still not. But I saw there is an new parse sdk that I haven't test yet (1.7.4). Did you test it ?

Comment: Not yet, they just release 1.7.3 which fixed a really bad bug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158193/ios-parse-pfobject-subclassing-with-swift-behaviour did you try my code below? From my testing it works 100%.

Comment: I've asked this question on the Google Groups Parse - Ask Parse Anything.

Comment: No solution? If I pin and unpin with labels, it works, otherwise not...weird

Comment: Guess this problem was the reason they decided to shut down Parse!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted the support team about the problem where you can't unpin an object that has a referenced object, so I'm sharing the thread for those interested:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/138298746504630/

The support person said it was By Design, but upon my request to improve this specification, he told me he would tell the team about it.

Comment: By design - interesting. Thanks for the post, I asked the question on the Monthly Q & A, and posted on the google group forum with zero response.

Comment: So not now news on this? This makes no sense to me. Seems like a bad design. Least now I can finish my app and not allow deleting unless you are online. I am yet to find a good example of how best to use the local store with offline / online status. Is this a viable alternative to core data ? Should I move to cloudKit ? So many questions....

Comment: Yea, it seems still unresolved. I'm trying to move to [Orma](https://github.com/gfx/Android-Orma) from Parse Local Storage. It has simple design like Parse Local Storage and works fast.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons this is not working for you is because there might still be objects in your local datastore that have relation with the object you want to unpin. To do this properly, unpin all those objects first and then unpin the target object.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work but using the follow workflow.

When I create a new object, and am ready to save I do the following 2 steps

```
    newThing.saveEventually(nil)

    newThing.pinInBackgroundWithBlock { (res, errn) -> Void in
        // pinning is required for offline delete to work correct
        if errn != nil { return }
        //self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            // dismiss modal if required...
        //})
    }
```

Within my tableview I delete like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        self.myDataSource[indexPath.row].deleteEventually()
        self.myDataSource.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.myDataSource.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
    }
```

Fetching process, within the same tableview

1. Local Query - from local datastore - this directly updates my tableview - called first
2. Network Query - this does the unpinning and pinning, updates the tableview data source - once completed this calls the local Query again to update the table.

Here is my network query

```
func networkQuery() {

    let nquery = theQuery()

    nquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let temp = objects as? [YourObjectType] where error == nil {
            PFObject.unpinAllInBackground(self.myDataSource, block: { (resultBool, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil { return }
                PFObject.pinAllInBackground(temp, block: { (resultBool, error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil { return }
                    self.localQuery()
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to break this creating new items, on and offline - deleting items on and offline - all works. Hope it helps, couldn't find any examples online so only go it to work with trail and error.... painful process, but working like a charm now.

Comment: I found that I had,  PFQuery.clearAllCachedResults() in my code for when I log in. Since removing this the above code has been working as expected from the testing performed so far.

Comment: I have the same issue but I can't see where you're unpinning or deleting anything in your .Delete code above?  How do you update your local data store to show that the object has been unpinned?

Comment: self.myDataSource[indexPath.row].deleteEventually() should unpin it. I've since given up on this project as Parse say that you cannot delete items that haven't been synced it. I asked Parse on forum and ask parse anything and got no response. The answer I've marked correct does confirm this "odd" practice

Answer (score 0):

After doing R & D on parse.com
I come to know that you can unpin objects from local storage once they are stored on cloud. B'coz parse is basically used for storing data on cloud so it allow unpinning of data after storing on cloud.
eg.

```
- (void)syncDataToCloud:(id)sender {
    PFQuery *qry = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Person"];
    [qry fromLocalDatastore];
    NSArray *arr = [qry findObjects];
    [PFObject saveAllInBackground:arr block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            DisplayAlert(@"Sync successful.");
        } else {
            DisplayAlert(@"Sync unsuccessful");
        }
    }];
    [PFObject unpinAll:arr];
}
```

it works for me...!! :)

Comment: Couldn't be that objects you were unable to unpin were pinned with the name? If so, they can be unpinned only with `PFObject.unpinAllObjectsWithName("yourPinName")`