# iOS Parse PFObject Subclassing with Swift Behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, subclass, pfobject

I have a strange issue, my subclassing works in all my view controllers except one.

I have imported everything that is required, but this one class is giving me the

> "Missing argument for parameter 'className' in call"

My subclass

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class Session : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Session"
    }

}
```

// i have removed the non important info

I perform the

```
Session.registerSubclass()
```

In the app delegate

In EVERY class I have i can create a session via

```
var se = Session()
```

But in this one class, this will not work.

The class

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class PurchaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var se = Session()
        // gives me an the above error
    }

}
```

I've tried deleting the class, creating a new one even with a new name - still does not work.

**MORE INFO**

Ok... something made me try removing some local class Vars from the classes where the object creation works, I found that by removing

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()! as! FighterUser
```

// This is my subclassed PFUser object

Causes that class to throw there error, and adding this var into the ViewController that was not working before stops the error

**Any logic to how / why this occurs? A bug ?**

This works

```
import Parse
import UIKit

class PurchaseViewController: UIViewController {

let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()! as! FighterUser

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var se = Session()

}
```

**More Info 2**

Even just adding

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
```

Removes the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it's a bug that will be addressed in 1.7.3 https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1647055045527392/